# Inserting timestamp in Oracle from asp ( not a valid month)

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

```
update users Set USER_ACCOUNT_DIS = to_timestamp('6/18/2013 1:41:05 PM','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') Where user_id='mytestuser'
```

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01843: not a valid month

i am getting the date as the "Now()" from classic asp see below:

```
sqlText4="update users " 
                sqlText4=sqlText4 & "Set  USER_ACCOUNT_DIS =  to_timestamp('" & Now()&"','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  "
                sqlText4=sqlText4 & " Where user_id='"&p_user_id&"'"
                Response.Write sqlText4
                objconnencore.Execute(sqlText4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format template parameter in the `to_timestamp()` function is wrong.

Try:

```
to_timestamp('" & Now()&"','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')
```